# How to deal single quote in filename path ?? (Android SQLite)

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, android-studio

ERROR : near "s": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM 'sp_downloadfile' WHERE filename='It's Easy to be Happy'

Comment: Use escape character (slash \) filename = 'it\'s ...

Comment: Here` DELETE FROM 'sp_downloadfile' WHERE filename='It''s Easy to be Happy'`

Comment: Does the literal value is inserted into the query text directly or like a parameter? When directly then double each inner quote, when like a parameter then wrap it with REPLACE() function which will replace each single quote with doubled one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#sqlEscapeString(java.lang.String))

Comment: thanks dude, i think this is the easiest one